# What geometry of magnet is typical for end-of-shaft Hall angle sensing?

Tags: hall-effect, magnet, shaft-position

While selecting parts for shaft angle sensing, I often have difficulty selecting magnets to act as the rotating magnetic field for a Hall angle sensor.

I've ended up selecting diametrically magnetized neodymium disc-magnets in the past, but these have some difficulties:

1. They're very cylindrical which makes it tough to fix them in place rotationally, there is nothing to key against
2. They don't have any visual indication of installation angle; how can an assembly procedure take this into account?
3. They seem to have very poor availability

I'm not looking for specific suppliers here, I'm wondering about the general engineering approach: is this a very niche application where I should expect to consult with suppliers, spend the effort getting low-volume quotes, or is there a simpler approach?

I've been wondering whether it would make more sense to use a rectangular magnet, which are obviously easier to tell the direction of polarization, and insert this magnet into a slot cut into the end of the shaft. This would solve the availability and alignment issues.

However, this approach never seems to be used in manufacturer white-sheets for configuring Hall sensors.

What's the typical approach for designing or sourcing an end-of-shaft angle-sensing magnet?